# The joint density of X and Y is given by...

Tags: functions, independence, variance, density-function

The joint density of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=
\left\{\begin{matrix}(x+y), \mbox{ } 0\leq x \leq1 , 0\leq y \leq1
\\ 0,  \mbox{   otherwise}\end{matrix}\right.$$

a) Evaluate $f_{X}(X)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$.
b) Are $X$ and $Y$ independent?
c) Evaluate $Var[X]$.

I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Please let me know if something is off in my solutions. Thanks for reading!!

My solutions:

a) $$f_{X}(x) = \int_{0}^{1}(x+y)dy = \left [ xy+\frac{y^{2}}{2} \right ]\Big|_0^1=x+\frac{1}{2}.$$
$$f_{Y}(y) = \int_{0}^{1}(x+y)dx = \left [ \frac{x^{2}}{2}+yx \right ]\Big|_0^1=y+\frac{1}{2}.$$
b) $X$ and $Y$ are independent if $f_{X,Y} = f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y)$.
From a, $$f_{X}(x)f_{Y}(y) = (x+\frac{1}{2})(y+\frac{1}{2}) = xy +  \frac{1}{2}x+ \frac{1}{2}y +\frac{1}{4}.$$
From given, $$f_{X,Y}= x+y.$$
So, since $xy +  \frac{1}{2}x+ \frac{1}{2}y +\frac{1}{4} \neq x+y$, $X$ and $Y$ are NOT independent.

c)$$ Var[X] = E[X^{2}] - E[X]^{2}.$$ $$E[X^{2}] = \int_{a}^{b}x^{2}f_{X}(x)dx = \int_{0}^{1}(x^{3}+ \frac{1}{2}x^{2})dx = \left [ \frac{x^{4}}{4} +\frac{x^{3}}{6} \right ]\Big|_0^1$$ $$= \frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{6}= \frac{3+2}{12}= \frac{5}{12}.$$
$$E[X]^{2} = (\int_{a}^{b}xf_{X}(x)dx)^{2} = (\int_{0}^{1}(x^{2}+ \frac{1}{2}x)dx)^{2} = )\left [ \frac{x^{3}}{3} +\frac{x^{2}}{4} \right ]\Big|_0^1)^{2}.(\frac{7}{12})^{2}=\frac{49}{144}.$$ $$\mbox{So, } Var[X] = \frac{5}{12} -\frac{49}{144}= \frac{60-49}{144}= \frac{11}{144}.$$

Comment: I see! So, do you mean that it should be $f_{X}(x) = x+\frac{1}{2}$ for $0<x<\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: I mean for $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Ignore me I was thinking about discrete distributions haha. You are indeed correct as in your questions :) I am loosing my mind.

Comment: Ah ok! You confused me for a second there! I got into panic mode.

Comment: You mean correct as in what I put in the OP is correct? For all three parts? :|

Comment: Well almost. Just in $E[X]^{2} = (\int_{a}^{b}x^{2}f_{X}(x)dx)^{2}$ you should have $E[X]^{2} = (\int_{a}^{b}xf_{X}(x)dx)^{2}$ . So other than funky latex where in your last line you magically turn 144 into 244, you nailed it. In my view. :)

Comment: Watchu mean? It was 144 aaaall along. :) And for the E[X] I typed it wrong, but thanks!

Comment: Oh it was all you ;) I think I just confused you. Help me.

Comment: Nah I got it. If you need help, take a break and watch Lucas the Spider.